# Deferred Queue in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, deferred, task-queue

I'm trying to perform some task in the deferred task queue and I need to execute another task on the successful completion of the task in deferred queue. Say, for example, I need to delete all the files stored at a given path and later, after successful deletion of all the files I want to start creating the files again.

Below is the sample code of how I'm trying to achieve it currently. Unfortunately, it raises the following exception:

> raise PermanentTaskFailure(e)
>   PermanentTaskFailure: 'module' object has no attribute 'DeleteTitanFiles'

The other task to be performed after the deletion of files in the deferred queue does not necessarily have to be another task, it can be anything, even simple print statement. The point is, the control should return to next statement after the execution of deletion.

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google3.apphosting.contrib.titan.files import files
from google.appengine.ext import deferred
import logging

TITAN_FILES_PATH = '/lovish-abc/'

BATCH_SIZE = 250

range_titan = 0

def _GetFileCount():
    return files.Files.count(TITAN_FILES_PATH, recursive=True)

file_count = _GetFileCount()

print _GetFileCount()

def CreateTitanFiles(path, start):
    logging.warning('In the CreateTitanFiles method')
    filecount = _GetFileCount()
    if filecount < 1000:
        range_titan = start + BATCH_SIZE
        for z in xrange(start, range_titan):
            titan_files = files.File(TITAN_FILES_PATH + 'file' + str(z) + '.json')
            titan_files.write(content='adasdad')
        logging.info("######sdgdgds")
        deferred.defer(
            CreateTitanFiles, TITAN_FILES_PATH, range_titan)



def DeleteTitanFiles(path):
    logging.info('In the DeleteTitanFiles method')

    filecount = _GetFileCount()

    if filecount > 0:
        titan_files = files.Files.list(
            TITAN_FILES_PATH, limit=BATCH_SIZE)
        titan_files.delete()
    else:
        CreateTitanFiles(TITAN_FILES_PATH, 0)


def CallDeleteTitanFiles(path):
    logging.warning('In the CallDeleteTitanFiles method')

    filecount = _GetFileCount()

    while filecount > 0:
        try:
            deferred.defer(DeleteTitanFiles, TITAN_FILES_PATH)
            filecount = _GetFileCount()
            logging.info('calling again')
            print filecount
        except Exception, e:
            raise e

CallDeleteTitanFiles(TITAN_FILES_PATH)
```

Any suggestions to achieve the desired results?

Comment: Why are you calling `CallDeleteTitanFiles` at module level? That will be executed when the module is first imported, which surely isn't what you want.

Comment: I was trying to execute this on an interactive console, so had to provide an entry point CallDeleteTitanFiles(TITAN_FILES_PATH) simply puts DeleteTitanFiles method in queue

Answer (score 0):

This note from [Limitations of the deferred library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred#limitations-of-the-deferred-library) *might* be related to why you're getting that error:

> - You can't pass a method defined in the request handler module.
>
> The last point above deserves special attention: passing a method
>   defined in the request handler module - the module specified as a
>   request handler in app.yaml - will not work. You can call
>   deferred.defer from the request handler module, but the function you
>   are passing to it must be defined elsewhere!

To execute your code in the interactive console you don't **need to** instantiate the call in the module.

Assuming your module is called `my_module.py` you could invoke `CallDeleteTitanFiles()` in the console like this instead:

```
from my_module import CallDeleteTitanFiles, TITAN_FILES_PATH
CallDeleteTitanFiles(TITAN_FILES_PATH)
```